# R: add a new column with values based on another column, indexing by category

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

How do I add a new column with values based on another column, indexing by those values? To explain better I have data like that:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
DT <-data.table(contract=1:7,code=c("yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no"),material=c(12,12,12,13,13,14,14))

contract code material
    1     yes       12
    2     yes       12
    3      no       12
    4      no       13
    5     yes       13
    6      no       14
    7      no       14
```

And I need to add a fourth column "status", which will be based on the value in "code, indexed by "material". So, if material 12 contains a "yes", all status rows for that material will contain "done", and if material 14 doesn't contain a "yes", all status rows for that material will contain "rejected". The important thing is the indexing by material, like so:

```
 contract code material  status
    1     yes       12    done
    2     yes       12    done
    3      no       12    done
    4      no       13    done 
    5     yes       13    done
    6      no       14    rejected
    7      no       14    rejected
```

Any advices on how to implement that? Thanks

Comment: I think that's not a great way to structure your data, but `DT[, status := if (any(code == "yes")) "done" else "rejected", by=material]` You'll probably want to have a look at the introductory materials, which will cover this sort of thing: http://r-datatable.com/Getting-started

Comment: Ok thanks, will definitely take a look at the materials.